# Duplicating and modifying rows based on datetime

Tags: r, datetime, duplicates, row, rbind

I have got have a data.table that looks like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ID=c("A001","A002","A003","A004"),start_time=c('2019-06-18 05:18:00','2020-03-04 05:00:00',
                 '2019-05-10 19:00:00','2020-01-06 22:42:00'),end_time=c('2019-06-18 08:41:00','2020-03-04 05:04:00',
                 '2019-05-10 19:08:00','2020-01-07 03:10:00'))
 ID      

    start_time            end_time duration
1: A001 2019-06-18 05:18:00 2019-06-18 08:41:00 203 mins
2: A002 2020-03-04 05:59:00 2020-03-04 06:04:00   5 mins
3: A003 2019-05-10 19:00:00 2019-05-10 19:08:00   8 mins
4: A004 2020-01-06 22:42:00 2020-01-07 03:10:00 268 mins
```

Duration was simply calculated as

```
dt$start_time <- as.POSIXct(dt$start_time, tz='UTC')  
dt$end_time <- as.POSIXct(dt$end_time, tz='UTC')
dt <- dt %>% mutate(duration = (end_time-start_time))
```

I need to duplicate rows where duration is larger than the end of the hour from start_time (records that cover > 1 hour). I need to change for them start time (beginning of the hour), end time - end of hour OR the original end time if if's the last row (last viewing hour),and duration accordingly, so that the final output would look like:

```
    dt_expected <- data.table(ID=c("A001","A001","A001","A001","A002","A002","A003","A004","A004","A004","A004","A004","A004"),
start_time=c('2019-06-18 05:18:00','2019-06-18 06:00:00','2019-06-18 07:00:00','2019-06-18 08:00:00', '2020-03-04 05:59:00', '2020-03-04 06:00:00',  '2019-05-10 19:00:00',
'2020-01-06 22:42:00', '2020-01-06 23:00:00','2020-01-07 00:00:00','2020-01-07 01:00:00','2020-01-07 02:00:00','2020-01-07 03:00:00'),
end_time=c('2019-06-18 05:59:00','2019-06-18 06:59:00','2019-06-18 07:59:00','2019-06-18 08:41:00','2020-03-04 05:59:00','2020-03-04 06:04:00',   '2019-05-10 19:08:00',    '2020-01-06 22:59:00','2020-01-06 23:59:00','2020-01-07 00:59:00','2020-01-07 01:59:00', '2020-01-07 02:59:00','2020-01-07 03:10:00'), 
duration = c(12,60,60,41,1,4,8,18,60,60,60,60,10))
```

Note that records for ID A002 should also be duplicated as duration happened in 2 different hours.

```
      ID          start_time            end_time duration
 1: A001 2019-06-18 05:18:00 2019-06-18 05:59:00       12
 2: A001 2019-06-18 06:00:00 2019-06-18 06:59:00       60
 3: A001 2019-06-18 07:00:00 2019-06-18 07:59:00       60
 4: A001 2019-06-18 08:00:00 2019-06-18 08:41:00       41
 5: A002 2020-03-04 05:59:00 2020-03-04 05:59:00        1
 6: A002 2020-03-04 06:00:00 2020-03-04 06:04:00        4
 7: A003 2019-05-10 19:00:00 2019-05-10 19:08:00        8
 8: A004 2020-01-06 22:42:00 2020-01-06 22:59:00       18
 9: A004 2020-01-06 23:00:00 2020-01-06 23:59:00       60
10: A004 2020-01-07 00:00:00 2020-01-07 00:59:00       60
11: A004 2020-01-07 01:00:00 2020-01-07 01:59:00       60
12: A004 2020-01-07 02:00:00 2020-01-07 02:59:00       60
13: A004 2020-01-07 03:00:00 2020-01-07 03:10:00       10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty close to what you're looking for.

This creates new rows of start and end times, one row for each hour using `map` from `purrr`.

Then, for each `ID`, it will determine `start_time` and `end_time` using `pmin`.

First, for the `end_time`, it takes the minimum value between that row's `end_time` and an hour later than the `start_time` for that row. For example, the first row for A001 would have `end_time` of 6:00, which is the `ceiling_date` time for 5:18 to the nearest hour, and less than 6:18 from the sequence generated from `map`. For the last row for A001, the `end_time` is 8:41, which is less than the `ceiling_date` time of 9:00.

The `start_time` will take the minimum value between the last row's `end_time` and that row's `start_time`. For example, the second row of A001 will have 6:00, which is the row above's `end_time` which is less than 6:18 from the sequence generated from `map`.

Note that one row has 0 minutes for `duration` - the time fell right on the hour (19:00:00). These could be filtered out.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

dt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(start_time = map(start_time, ~seq.POSIXt(., ceiling_date(end_time, "hour"), by = "hour"))) %>%
  unnest(start_time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(end_time = pmin(ceiling_date(start_time, unit = "hour"), end_time),
         start_time = pmin(floor_date(lag(end_time, default = first(end_time)), unit = "hour"), start_time),
         duration = difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "mins"))
```

**Output**

```
   ID    start_time          end_time            duration
   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
 1 A001  2019-06-18 05:18:00 2019-06-18 06:00:00 42 mins 
 2 A001  2019-06-18 06:00:00 2019-06-18 07:00:00 60 mins 
 3 A001  2019-06-18 07:00:00 2019-06-18 08:00:00 60 mins 
 4 A001  2019-06-18 08:00:00 2019-06-18 08:41:00 41 mins 
 5 A002  2020-03-04 05:59:00 2020-03-04 06:00:00  1 mins 
 6 A002  2020-03-04 06:00:00 2020-03-04 06:04:00  4 mins 
 7 A003  2019-05-10 19:00:00 2019-05-10 19:00:00  0 mins 
 8 A003  2019-05-10 19:00:00 2019-05-10 19:08:00  8 mins 
 9 A004  2020-01-06 22:42:00 2020-01-06 23:00:00 18 mins 
10 A004  2020-01-06 23:00:00 2020-01-07 00:00:00 60 mins 
11 A004  2020-01-07 00:00:00 2020-01-07 01:00:00 60 mins 
12 A004  2020-01-07 01:00:00 2020-01-07 02:00:00 60 mins 
13 A004  2020-01-07 02:00:00 2020-01-07 03:00:00 60 mins 
14 A004  2020-01-07 03:00:00 2020-01-07 03:10:00 10 mins
```